Why does my raster look different after clipping it by a mask layer using QGIS?
I have a Digital Elevation Model of Europe and I want to clip it to the extent of Germany. To do so, I am using Clip Raster by Mask Layer with the external frontier of Germany as the mask layer. However, the output raster looks slightly different from the original raster. I have tried checking the box to keep the resolution of the input raster, but this made no difference. Copying the style of the original raster and pasting it to the output raster didn't help either.
How can I keep the output raster looking the same as the original raster?
On the first picture, you can see the original raster. On the second picture, you can see the output raster within Germany and the original raster in the background.




The black dots? Seems to be hillshades, created by the difference in horizontal units (degrees) and vertical units (meters). Does the issue solve if you reproject the clipped image to a meter-based projected system with warp process?

Probably because the clipped raster has different statistics (min/max values).

Can you also post the symbology for each of your layers? I'm not 100% clear on your differences as the pics are very zoomed out, but it's more likely a display issue than a data issue.

Open the layer properties and make sure that the image enhancing parameters are the same (exact values, not min/max) . Does the layers still look different?
